# Stopping window.location.replace from redirecting

Tags: javascript

I have an html code that I can't change but can load .js file into it.

Can I add some java script code to stop `window.location.replace` from working?

Comment: look into the history api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: [Doesn't look like it, no](http://imgur.com/XwJckJt).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: How does the history API allow you to *prevent* a `location.replace` call from working?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Yeah. I also tried replacing the `location` object (directly, which didn't work of course because of the special way assignment is handled by it, and also via `Object.defineProperty`, which also didn't work).

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum i don't need to return to previous page, I need to stop the redirect itself

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this, you'd have to either replace the `replace` function on `location`, replace `location` entirely, or replace *`window`* entirely (which wouldn't be a guarantee, since you can also access it as `this` at global scope in loose mode, and via a couple of other aliases).

Neither appears to be possible, not even with `Object.defineProperty`.

Benjamin mentioned the history API, but I don't see anything in the history API that allows you to cancel a navigation initiated by `location.replace`.

So I don't think you can do this.

*(CW because this was a community effort.)*

Comment: Is there any other solution regardles of location.replace? Can i stop page from reloading after location.replace occur?

Comment: @mgalesic: As close as you can come is to use an `onbeforeunload` handler to ask the browser to show the user a message which then lets the user choose whether to stay on the page. Some browsers (Firefox for instance) don't even show *your* message, just a generic message.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try onbeforeunload

Comment: @mgalesic Another alternative would be to try to intercept the functions that _call_ `location.replace`, and replace them with your alternatives, but it could easily get messy with trying to keep the right contexts etc.

Comment: @James Thorpe I think I cant because code is not inside function, its only inside condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can't redefine `location.replace` because it's not a configurable property.

However, you can try replacing the entire `location` object with a similar object (e.g. a proxy) but with your custom `replace`.

The problem is that `window.replace` isn't configurable neither, but you can shadow it in an inner scope:

```
(function() {
  function customReplace() { /* ... */ }
  var location = new Proxy(Object.create(window.location), {
    get: function(target, property, receiver) {
      if(property === 'replace') return customReplace;
      return window.location[property];
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
      return window.location[property] = value;
      return true;
    },
  });
  location.replace('http://example.com'); // Nothing happens
  location.host; // Still works
  location.host = 'example.com'; // Still works
})();
```