# Expand JavaScript object in the console on the next page

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

I am debugging JavaScript tags on a website using Developer Tools.

Specifically I have been trying to debug the values generated on the click of a button, by using a TMS specific function which should have an output of the form :

```
Arguments(3) [value, value2, {…}]
```

Since these buttons redirect to another page, I **cannot expand** this object to see the values.

I have tried many solutions, like using `JSON.stringify()` in the function :

```
function debugEvents(var1, var2) 
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments));
}
```

Which displayed `null` to me.

I tried saving it in `localStorage` like the following :

```
function debugEvents(var1, var2) 
{
    localStorage.setItem("test",arguments));
}
```

When trying to access it :

```
localStorage.getItem("test")
```

I get :

```
[object Arguments]
```

And when I try `JSON.stringify` before saving to `localStorage`:

```
function debugEvents(var1, var2) 
{
    localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(arguments)));
}
```

When trying to access it :

```
localStorage.getItem("test")
```

I get :

```
null
```

So I guess `JSON.stringify` is not good for the format of the arguments object, but I wonder if I have an alternative to check the value of this object in the console of developer tools to be able to access it even on the next page.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the ability to alter the event listener that redirects on button click, so that you can prevent the redirection from occurring?

Comment: if you know the properties of the argument object you can use java script destructing. to get value in other pages you need to save the object, you may use localStorage  or sessionStorage .

Comment: I don't think `arguments` will ever be null - if there are no arguments, won't it be an empty array-like object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance unfortunately I don't have access to the website source code. The point of my debugging is to check the values generated from the event implemented by the developers on the button click. I hope I clarified

Comment: @CertainPerformance is right, it should never be `null` but at least an object. You might want to try `JSON.stringify(Array.from(arguments))` though

Comment: Thanks, do you know how exactly the page gets replaced? Is it in a `<form>` without a `preventDefault()`, or is there Javascript that assigns to `window.location.href`? Unfortunately, `window.location` does not look to be [monkeypatchable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35558709/stopping-window-location-replace-from-redirecting), though depending on the circumstances, you might be able to debug by blocking the built-in script and running it yourself via a userscript (with the redirect functionality removed)

Comment: can you provide the page which you are trying??